# Is this an interrogative sentence or rhetorical question?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The text below is quite long, but in order to share the exact context, I'm pasting it. You can read the full text here on the Gutenberg Project page(https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/huxleya-bravenewworld/huxleya-bravenewworld-00-h.html#chapter07).

My question is whether "***what hadn't he hoped***" in the text is just an interrogative sentence or rhetorical question. And I also want to know what the phrase means.

I'd appreciate it if you would answer my question. Thank you.

> ...
> 'And now, my friends,' said the Arch-Community-Songster of Canterbury,
> in that beautiful ringing voice with which he led the proceedings at
> Ford's Day Celebrations, 'Now, my friends, I think perhaps the time
> has come...' He rose, put down his glass, brushed from his purple
> viscose waistcoat the crumbs of a considerable collation, and walked
> towards the door.
>
> Bernard darted forward to intercept him.
>
> 'Must you really, Arch-Songster?... It's very early still. I'd hoped
> you would...'
>
> Yes, ***what hadn't he hoped***, when Lenina confidentially told him that
> the Arch-Community-Songster would accept an invitation if it were
> sent. 'He's really rather sweet, you know.' And she had shown Bernard
> the little golden zipper-fastening in the form of a T which the
> Arch-Songster had given her as a memento of the week-end she had spent
> at the Diocesan Singery. To meet the Arch-Community-Songster of
> Canterbury and Mr. Savage. Bernard had proclaimed his triumph on every
> invitation card. But the Savage had chosen this evening of all
> evenings to lock himself up in his room, to shout 'Háni!' and even (it
> was lucky that Bernard didn't understand Zuñi) 'Sons éso tse-ná!' What
> should have been the crowning moment of Bernard's whole career had
> turned out to be the moment of his greatest humiliation.
>
> 'I'd so much hoped...' he stammeringly repeated, looking up at the
> great dignitary with pleading and distracted eyes.
> ...

Comment: One clue is there's no question mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rhetorical question, meaning that he had been hoping for a great deal (which apparently wasn't going to happen).

Questions like *What didn't he bring? - What didn't she tell me?* are an idiom implying (with some exaggeration) that so much was included that it would be difficult to think of anything that was left out.